# How do I set a header on the request generated by FileReference?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

How do I add my own request header to the POST requests generated by FileReference.upload()?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

From the docs:

> The requestHeaders property of the
>   URLRequest object is ignored; custom
>   HTTP request headers are not supported
>   in uploads or downloads.

EDIT: just fixed some specifics.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "file's header".  I'm talking about HTTP request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried created an [URLRequest](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) with its own [URLRequestHeader](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html) entries?

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/post.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
request.requestHeaders.push(header);

fileRef.upload(request);
```

Comment: Fantastic idea, but it doesn't work. :(  from docs: "The requestHeaders property of the URLRequest object is ignored; custom HTTP request headers are not supported in uploads or downloads."

Comment: Ouch. Thanks, didn't realize that. Sounds weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a same problem, use file upload via `URLLoader`, and use [zehs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729887/how-do-i-set-a-header-on-the-request-generated-by-filereference/3730442#3730442) solution to setup headers.

Just put your file inside of `request.data`, and setup method to POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can UrlRequest as before but you use a helper class to send the content of the file. Here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12933681/1753025